# Переадресация после отправки формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть некая форма, в ней поля. Не моя, я пишу под нее userJS.

Я её заполнил и отправил.

Как сделать после отправки переход на другую страницу?

Пробовал вот так:

```
$('div form').submit(function(){
    location.href = 'qwerty.ru';
});

$('div form').submit(function(){
    this.submit();
    location.href = 'qwerty.ru';
});
```

Comment: А у функции отправки нет события success?

Comment: success есть у ajax'а у submit нету ж..

Comment: так тоже пробовал, не выходит ничего...ни так ни через вызов потом trigger('submit')

Comment: Засунуть в onclick

Comment: что именно, и зачем кликовый обработчик то вообще ?

Comment: Ну форма-то по кнопке отправляется?

Comment: В том то и дело, что разницы не имеет, на какое событие подвешена отправка, на клик, на сам сабмит, да хоть на потерю фокуса у инпута..надо обработать саму отправку, одновременно с отправкой данных и переходом...блин какой вопрос задаю уже по счету и отвечаю на него сам же..решилось вот так:
$('form').submit( function(){ 
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                location.href = 'site.com'
            }, 250) }).trigger('submit');

Comment: @pirogi это не решение, это хак.

Comment: @Petr Abdulin в смысле хак, и что хак, что я написал ?

Comment: В смысле, что работоспособность вашего решения обусловлена стечением обстоятельств, которые позволяют ему работать. Но возможны ситуации когда оно не сработает корректно.

Answer (score 5):

В том виде как вы пытаетесь - никак. Но зачем вам вообще форма? Собрали данные и отправили POST, а по callback делать переход:

```
$('div form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // отменяем отправку формы

    // собираем данные
    // отправляем
    $.ajax({/* ... */}).done(function(result) {
        // переход
        window.location.href = "http://test.com";
    });
});
```

Comment: В новых версиях jQuery не `done`, а `then`.